# Wrapping event handler callback in Observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to find a pattern for wrapping an event callback from a library to an RxJS Observable.

The library I'm using registers handlers for events like this:

```js
const someHandler = (args) => {}`;
const resultCallback = (result) => {}`;

Library.addHandler('SOME_EVENT', someHandler, resultCallback);
Library.removeHandler('SOME_EVENT', someHandler, resultCallback);
```

The `resultCallback` is a callback that returns if the handler was registered successfully.

---

Ideally, I would like to pass the handler in as a parameter of the function, and emit it's result.

I don't know how I can emit the value of the handler from this function, while also maintaining an object reference to the handler for removal.

```js
addEventHandlerObservable<T>(handler: any): Observable<T> {

    return new Observale(observer => {

        SomeLibrary.addHandler('SOME_EVENT', handler,
        (result) => { 
            // was registered successfully?
            if(result.failed) {
                observer.error();
                observer.complete();
            }
        });

    });

}
```

Comment: @AluanHaddad `fromEvent` only works on specific event targets. this is not one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rxjs already did this for you, with the `fromEventPattern` observable.

```
const resultCallback = (result) => {}; // not hyper clear on the point of this

const events$ = fromEventPattern(
  (handler) => Library.addHandler('SOME_EVENT', handler, resultCallback),
  (handler) => Library.removeHandler('SOME_EVENT', handler, resultCallback);
);
```

you don't "pass in" the handler here. Your subscribe IS your handler:

```
events$.subscribe((val) => someHandler(val));
```

Comment: Thanks, "you don't pass in" is where it clicked.

Comment: The "resultCallback" is an async callback for the result of actually registering the handler, because there are conditions where it can fail, and this is how the library returns the result. 

So I would need to unsubscribe in the event it does.

Comment: In that case, I'd say make that function something like `(result) => { if (result.failed) { throw new Error('Event registration failed!'); } }` that should cause the observable to error out

Comment: Thanks, throwing an error doesn't complete the observable. But I can just pipe on a takeWhile() with a flag if it fails.

Comment: yup, that works if your goal is completion. I just thought you might want it to go to the error handler in the failed case

Comment: Good point thanks, I made a couple of BehaviourSubjects for the add and remove results so I can pipe some different scenarios before returning the actual event value.